# Convert byte array to objects C++ | C# Bitconverter in C++

Tags: c#, c++, udp, byte, bitconverter

I have a C++ server that receives a byte array from a client written in C# (I'm using SFML UDP sockets). In the client, I encode the packet information using `System.Bitconverter`.

How would I go about extracting the information from the packet on the C++ server given that it is received as a `string/char[]`. With Bitconverter in C#, I could just do `Bitconverter.GetBytes (...)`.

I'm not great in C++ so I apologise for the nooby question. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

The client (written for the Unity game engine):

```
// - Sending this Player's data: -

    byte[] buff = new byte[7 * sizeof(float) + 3 * sizeof (int)];

    int tag = 1;
    int curSize = 0;

    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(tag), 0, buff, curSize, sizeof (int));
    curSize += sizeof(int);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(id), 0, buff, curSize, sizeof(int));
    curSize += sizeof(int);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(GetComponent<controls>().killedID), 0, buff, curSize, sizeof(int));
    curSize += sizeof(int);


    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(transform.position.x), 0, buff, curSize, sizeof(float));
    curSize += sizeof(float);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(transform.position.y), 0, buff, curSize, sizeof(float));
    curSize += sizeof(float);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(transform.position.z), 0, buff, curSize, sizeof(float));
    curSize += sizeof(float);

    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(transform.eulerAngles.x), 0, buff, curSize, sizeof(float));
    curSize += sizeof(float);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(GetComponentInChildren<Camera> ().transform.eulerAngles.y), 0, buff, curSize, sizeof(float));
    curSize += sizeof(float);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(transform.eulerAngles.z), 0, buff, curSize, sizeof(float));
    curSize += sizeof(float);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(myGun.transform.eulerAngles.x), 0, buff, curSize, sizeof(float));
    curSize += sizeof(float);


    sendData(buff);

}
private void sendData(byte[] data)
{
    udp.Send(data, data.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your C++ and C# compilers agree about the size and shape of `int` and `float` *and* your client/server have matching endianness, you can do the following:

```
struct packet {
  int tag, id, killedID;
  float posX, posY, posZ;
  float rotX, rotY, rotZ;
  float rotGun;
};

packet read_packet(const char *in) {
    packet ret;
    ret.tag = *(int *)in; in += sizeof int;
    ret.int = *(int *)in; in += sizeof int;
    ret.posX = *(float *)in; in += sizeof float;
    ...
    return ret;
}
```

However, I would advise using [Flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/index.html#flatbuffers_overview) instead. This enables you to have a *single specification of the packet contents* and has tooling to generate the serialization code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C++ header-only library that may be of help. It is a port of C# `BitConverter` class for C++.

[BitConverter](https://github.com/YanjieHe/BitConverter)